# Webrtc navigator.mediaDevice.getCapabilitites shows EchoCancellation false is Safari 13.0.3

Tags: safari, webrtc, opentok

I m using webrtc in my project for audio alone, everything works fine in other browsers except safari.  The issue I am facing with safari is echo(i.e I am hearing my own voice but it's clean for the receiver end).

Using OpenTox

```
var options = {
               insertDefaultUI: false, 
               audioSource:"<id>",  
               height: 120,
               width: 180,
               insertMode: 'append',
               name: "voice session"
               }
OT.initPublisher(placeholder, options, (publisher) => {
  console.log(publisher.getAudioSource().getCapabilities())
})
```

When I pass these options to the publisher I am getting echo.

```
OT.initPublisher(placeholder, null, (publisher) => {
  console.log(publisher.getAudioSource().getCapabilities())
})
```

When I pass null to the publisher echo is not there in safari as well.

The output of both consoles are the same

```
{deviceId: "98152D568180063419A471521CA4EFFDD18240F4", echoCancellation: [true, true], sampleRate: {max: 96000, min: 8000}, volume: {max: 1, min: 0}}
```

When you look into console.log output's echoCancellation it says [true, true] which means noise cancellation is not there

Strange behavior with OT.initPublisher with Safari 13

Please help me how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue.
The audio only mode will not have echo cancellation.

My solution:
- Do not publish video and audio when create the publisher.
- When stream is ready (which is onStreamCreated event) then publish audio
- So then the audio echo is gone

Comment: It will be helpful if I can see some sample code for your approach